# Xcode 4: key binding for "Focus code blocks on hover"

Tags: keyboard, xcode

Xcode 4 has a `Focus code blocks on hover` setting in Preferences > Text Editing.
[image]

When you hover the mouse on a `Code folding ribbon`, the mentioned setting has the effect shown in image below. 
[image]
Also, the effect stays put when you navigate with the keyboard (even when you move focus to `Assistant editor`, `Navigator`, `Utilities`, ... but not to, say, `Organizer` or `Version editor`).

**How could you add a key binding for this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Go to **Settings > Keybindings** and search for *focus*.
- Then set your desired keybinding under **Code Folding > Focus Follows Selection**.

[image]

Comment: Was this added in Xcode 4.6? I could've sworn I already searched with "focus". :) Nevertheless, this is great. Thank you Bryan!

Comment: I'm not sure when this was added. This also works on Xcode 4.5.2, which is the oldest version that I have installed for my computers.

Comment: Now I remember: the menu entry was there in Xcode 4 from the get-go, but was [oddly disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926576/xcode-4-0-2-4a2002a-editor-code-folding-focus-follows-selection-grey-disa).

Comment: OMG I just discovered this feature... super useful!